# Use cookies to set country automatically in HttpWebRequest (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, http, redirect, cookies

I am trying to monitor some websites to get the changes and keep an history of that data, unfortunately, when I try to access some websites I get a "Country selection" screen as in https://www.gamestop.com. Since I am in Canada, I am offered to use ebgames.ca instead and I have to click on a link at the bottom to go to the US version.

I tried to set some cookies on my HttpWebRequest but it seems I am missing something, here is the relevant part of the code:

```
url = "https://www.gamestop.com";

CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie cookie_00 = new Cookie("LocaleCookie", "en_us") { Domain = "gamestop.com" };
CookieContainer.Add(cookie_00);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
```

No matter what I try, I always end up with the page with the country selection and the stream never contains the page that I want.

May you provide some help with this please?

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had to do the following, so my mistake:

```
Cookie cookie_00 = new Cookie("user_country", "CA") { Domain = "gamestop.com" };
```

Thank you again.